# scikit-learn regression prediction results are too good. What did I mess up?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, azure-machine-learning-service

We have some ML models running in Azure on top of the Azure ML Studio platform (the initial drag & drop system). All has been good for over a year but we need to move on so we can scale better. So I'm working on rewriting these in Python using scikit-learn and testing them in an Jupyter notebook.

The good news/bad news is that our data to train on is fairly small (several hundred records in a database). It's very imperfect data making very imperfect regression predictions, so error is to be expected. And that's fine. And for this question, it's good. Because the problem is that, when I test these models, the predictions are way too perfect. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, but I'm clearly doing **something** wrong.

The obvious things to suspect (in my mind) are that either I'm training on the test data or there's an obvious/perfect causation found via the correlations. My use of `train_test_split` tells me that I'm not training on my test data and I guarantee the second is false because of how messy this space is (we started doing manual linear regression on this data about 15 years ago, and still maintain Excel spreadsheets to be able to manually do it in a pinch, even if it's significantly less accurate than our Azure ML Studio models).

Let's look at the code. Here's the relevant portion of my Jupyter notebook (sorry if there's a better way to format this):

```
X = myData
y = myData.ValueToPredict
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, 
    y, 
    train_size = 0.75,
    test_size = 0.25)
print("X_train: ", X_train.shape)
print("y_train: ", y_train.shape)
print("X_test:  ", X_test.shape)
print("y_test:  ", y_test.shape)
```

> X_train:  (300, 17)
>
> y_train:  (300,)
>
> X_test:   (101, 17)
>
> y_test:   (101,)

```
ESTIMATORS = {
    "Extra Trees": ExtraTreesRegressor(criterion = "mse",
                                       n_estimators=10,
                                       max_features=16,
                                       random_state=42),
    "Decision Tree": DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion = "mse",
                                  splitter = "best",
                                       random_state=42),
    "Random Forest": RandomForestRegressor(criterion = "mse",
                                       random_state=42),
    "Linear regression": LinearRegression(),
    "Ridge": RidgeCV(),
}

y_test_predict = dict()
y_test_rmse = dict()
for name, estimator in ESTIMATORS.items():
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_test_predict[name] = estimator.predict(X_test)
    y_test_rmse[name] = np.sqrt(np.mean((y_test - y_test_predict[name]) ** 2)) # I think this might be wrong but isn't the source of my problem
for name, error in y_test_rmse.items():
    print(name + " RMSE: " + str(error))
```

> Extra Trees RMSE: 0.3843540838630157
>
> Decision Tree RMSE: 0.32838969545222946
>
> Random Forest RMSE: 0.4304701784728594
>
> Linear regression RMSE: 7.971345895791494e-15
>
> Ridge RMSE: 0.0001390197344951183

```
y_test_score = dict()
for name, estimator in ESTIMATORS.items():
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_test_predict[name] = estimator.predict(X_test)
    y_test_score[name] = estimator.score(X_test, y_test)
for name, error in y_test_score.items():
    print(name + " Score: " + str(error))
```

> Extra Trees Score: 0.9990166492769291
>
> Decision Tree Score: 0.999282165241745
>
> Random Forest Score: 0.998766521504593
>
> Linear regression Score: 1.0
>
> Ridge Score: 0.9999999998713534

I thought maybe I was doing the error metrics wrong, so I just looked at simple scores (which is why I included both). However, both show that these predictions are too good to be true. Keep in mind that the volume of inputs are small (~400 items in total?). And the data this is running over is essentially making predictions of a commodity consumption based on weather patterns, which is kind of a messy space to begin with, so lots of error should be present.

What am I doing wrong here?

(Also, if I can ask this question in a better way or provide more useful information, I'd greatly appreciate it!)

---

Here is a heatmap of the data. I indicated the value we're predicting.

[image: Seaborn heatmap of the data]

I also plotted a couple of those more important inputs vs the value we're predicting (color-coded by yet another dimension):

[image: A plot of values we're predicting]

Here's column #2, as asked about in comments
[image: Another plot]

---

## Solution!

As pointed out by @jwil, I wasn't pulling my `ValueToPredict` column out of my `X` variable. The solution was a one-liner added to remove that column:

```
X = myData
y = myData.ValueToPredict
X = X.drop("ValueToPredict", 1) # <--- ONE-LINE FIX!
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, 
    y, 
    train_size = 0.75,
    test_size = 0.25)
```

With this in place, my error & scores are much more where I expect:

> Extra Trees RMSE: 1.6170428819849574
>
> Decision Tree RMSE: 1.990459810552763
>
> Random Forest RMSE: 1.699801032532343
>
> Linear regression RMSE: 2.5265108241534397
>
> Ridge RMSE: 2.528721533965162
>
> Extra Trees Score: 0.9825944193611161
>
> Decision Tree Score: 0.9736274412836977
>
> Random Forest Score: 0.9807672396970707
>
> Linear regression Score: 0.9575098985510281
>
> Ridge Score: 0.9574355079097321

Comment: can you provide that data that you're actually using? What are the coefficients or feature importances in your regression / trees (respectively)?

Comment: Looks like due to some overfitting. Share dataset plz.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer @user3014097's questions. As for the data, I cannot share it as it's non-public data. If this is a matter of overfitting, how can I make it less prone to do this? I've been teaching myself this as I go - Python and ML, in general, are still pretty new to me. I'll see if I can attach a sns.heatmap of the data - I think this might help get what you're asking for, to a degree.

Comment: Do I see correctly that the value you are predicting is perfectly correlated with another feature, specifically 2nd one? Plot feature importance and it should be visible immediately.

Comment: There's definitely a very strong correlation there but definitely not perfect. The second value is effectively "number of people in largest class of users", so consumption obviously goes up as # of people goes up. The first three are 3 classes of people (where, in this dataset, the third is always 0 but the values in #1 and #2 change).

Comment: For linear / ridge regression look at 'estimator.coeff_', for trees look at 'estimator.feature_importances_'. my guess is one is going to be much much higher than others (the one that shows essentially a correlation of 1 in your plot above)

Comment: You're initializing _X = myData_ and _y = my.ValueToPredict_. This looks weird to me. Did you mean to write _X = my.Data_ or _y = myData.ValueToPredict_ ?

Comment: @VladIliescu - I had a typo when I manually renamed the variables to obfuscate their names. Fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out. `myData` is just a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; I strongly suspect that you have one or more features in your X data that is nearly perfectly correlated with the Y data. Usually this is bad, because those variables don't explain Y but are either explained by Y or jointly determined with Y. To troubleshoot this, consider performing a linear regression of Y on X and then using simple p values or AIC/BIC to determine which X variables are the least relevant. Drop these and repeat the process until your R^2 begins to drop seriously (though it will drop a little each time). The remaining variables will be the most relevant in prediction, and hopefully you'll be able to identify from that subset which variables are so tightly correlated with Y.

Comment: So are you saying that my use of the framework, splitting training vs test data, and all of that is correct? If you can give positive confirmation that what is here is correct, then that is the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: WAIT. In your code here you don't appear to drop ValueToPredict from your X. After assigning that data to Y, you need to make sure that you're removing it from X. That should definitely fix your problem.

Comment: That's it!! Doing this dropped my scores down to ~95-97% levels, which is exactly what I was expecting (99.99999-100% was unbelievable). I think that was *exactly* my problem. So I thought that the `train_test_split` knew to not train on the `y` column (as defined by `y`). I didn't know I had to pull that out of `X`.

Comment: I'm glad that worked! All that `train_test_split` does is randomly divide your observations into two groups, but leaves all the features intact for both groups.

Comment: That's definitely where my bad assumption was. I'm now going back through a few other proof-of-concepts where I've had the same problem and this is solving so many head-scratchers! Thank you soooo much! I first hit this about a month ago, spun for a day, then tabled it. Tried a couple times to figure out the problem since then with no luck. Wish I could buy you a beer or something. You have saved me a LOT of time! Thank you, random smart internet person!